# How to take the new values edited in the list to send it to server database.

Tags: android, scroll, baseadapter

Here is my adapter code where on edit field edited am calculating the 2 other fields and displaying through TextWatcher. There are 2 issues here. 
1. On scroll the values are changing to default values
2. How can I take the new values updated on click of a button 
Please help...thanks.

```
public class ItemListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<Itemlist> mProductList,medicineList;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
String newEditValu[];
Itemlist curProduct;
Itemlist list;
DataTranrfer df;


public ItemListAdapter(ArrayList<Itemlist> list, LayoutInflater inflater) {
    mProductList = list;
    mInflater = inflater;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mProductList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mProductList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewItem item;
    final int pos=position;
    medicineList=new ArrayList<Itemlist>();
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_medicine_list,null);
        item = new ViewItem();

        item.medicineTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMedicineName);
        item.medcineQuantity =(EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.etQuantity);
        item.itemDaily=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDailyText);
        item.itemNdays=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvNodays);
        item.itemTotal = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCost);
        convertView.setTag(item);


        ImageButton b2 = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        b2.setTag(position);
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                int pos = (int)arg0.getTag();
                mProductList.remove(pos);
                ItemListAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });

        convertView.setTag(item);
    } else {
        item = (ViewItem) convertView.getTag();
    }

    curProduct = mProductList.get(position);
    item.ref=position;
    item.medicineTitle.setText(curProduct.getmedicineName());
    item.itemDaily.setText("Daily: " + curProduct.getMedicineDaily());
    item.itemNdays.setText("Days: " + curProduct.medicineNoDays);
    item.itemTotal.setText("Rs." + curProduct.getMedicineTotal());
    item.medcineQuantity.setText("" + curProduct.getMedicineQuantity());

    ItemListAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();


    item.medcineQuantity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //ItemListAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            System.out.print("edit response" + s.toString());
            Itemlist curProduct = mProductList.get(position);
            if (item.medcineQuantity.getText().length() >= 0) {

                double dItemcost = Double.parseDouble(curProduct.getMedicineCost());
                double dItemDaily = Double.parseDouble(curProduct.getMedicineDaily());
                double dItemQuantity = Double.parseDouble(item.medcineQuantity.getText().toString());
                //double dItemQuantity = Double.parseDouble(myList.get(pos));
                double dItemDays = (dItemQuantity / dItemDaily);
                double dItemTotal = (dItemQuantity * dItemcost);



                item.medcineQuantity.setText("" +myList.get(pos));
                item.itemNdays.setText("Days: " + dItemDays);
                item.itemTotal.setText("Rs." + dItemTotal);

                list=new Itemlist();
                list.setmedicineName(curProduct.getmedicineName());
                list.setMedicineDaily(curProduct.getMedicineDaily());
                list.setMedicineQuantity(dItemQuantity);
                list.setMedicineCost("" + dItemcost);
                list.setMedicineTotal(dItemTotal);
                medicineList.add(list);

                for(int i=0;i<medicineList.size();i++)
                {
                    System.out.println("medicine list"+medicineList.toString());
                    System.out.println("medicine total at"+i+":"+medicineList.get(i).getMedicineTotal());
                }

            }

        }
    });


    return convertView;
}

private class ViewItem {
    TextView medicineTitle,itemDaily,itemNdays,itemTotal;
    EditText medcineQuantity;
    int ref;
}
```

}

Comment: use notifyDatasetChanged()

Comment: Its being used.  Am i using it in the right place?. where exactly i have to notify?

Comment: try to add at the end of `afterTextChanged()`